# Identify SMD DC-DC converter chip

Tags: identification, dc-dc-converter, surface-mount, converter

I am trying to identify the DC-DC converter chip in the images below (two variants of the same PCB). Input (B1) is in the range of 20-60V and output is 12V. I have found devices from Torex Semicon with similar pinouts, but as far as I can see none of their devices will accept input voltages up to 60V.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: My experience with reverse engineering is that if google doesn't pop up an answer, it's probably made in Asia, I would then reach out to my sources to help find it. Not a direct answer, but a solution if you know people who know the asian markets

Answer (score 1):

The markings seem to match with a [ZGSEMI (中广芯源) SC72001](http://www.zgsemi.com/product/jy/dc/). I can't find a datasheet, but this [shop](https://item.hqchip.com/2500311083.html) has a picture with markings that match with the 2nd picture.

[image]

(source: [hqchip.com](https://item.hqchip.com/2500311083.html))

Another DC-DC converter by the same manufacturer ([SC9902](https://www.dianyuan.com/upload/community/2021/03/25/1616660165-52831.pdf)) has very similar markings, so I think it's save to say that it's at least the right manufacturer.

[image]

Update: I found what seems to be a screenshot of the beginning of the first page of the datasheet:

[image]

(source:[blog.csdn.net](https://blog.csdn.net/jgxdz086/article/details/127608421))

In and of itself that wouldn't be too interesting, but searching some of the text in the datasheet I found the [PL2082](https://bbs.16rd.com/thread-603712-1-1.html) DC-DC converter which seems to copy all of the specs of the SC72001 verbatim. It has screenshots of a datasheet available though and that shows a pinout that matches OP's schematic pretty well:

[image]

(Source: [bbs.16rd.com](https://bbs.16rd.com/data/attachment/forum/202304/21/172627xiycf9vssmvcrww1.png))

This leads me to believe that there are variants of this converter available from different "brands" which could explain why the markings are different on the variants in OP's pictures.